# Creating objects in python within a formatted text file

Tags: python

I have a text file that is formatted as such:

```
T    timestamp
U    username
W    text
```

Is there a way to create an object within the text file with the T U and W being attributes? I have only done scripting in Python and nothing object orientated so I'm a bit lost.

I need to parse this giant text file and I am currently reading the file, line by line, looking for the 'W' attribute but it might be more useful to have the entire object.

edit: it looks like this

```
total number:18572084
T   2009-06-01 21:43:59
U   http://twitter.com/burtonator 
W   No Post Title

T   2009-06-01 21:47:23
U   http://twitter.com/burtonator
W   No Post Title

T   2009-06-02 01:15:44
U   http://twitter.com/burtonator
W   No Post Title

T   2009-06-02 05:17:52
U   http://twitter.com/burtonator
W   No Post Title
```

Comment: What do you mean *"within the text file"*? Do you mean *from* the text file? Of course you can parse a line, extract some values and turn them into an object of some kind.

Comment: is -every-single-entry- going to have the exact same "T, U , W" ?

Comment: Does the pattern of  "T    timestamp \nU    username \nW    text" repeat throughout the file? Are there empty lines between these groups of three? Seeing more input text would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need one way of doing it but here are two variations and a single file reading function that doesn't read the entire file at once (it stores 3-4 lines at most):

```
# **kwarg is a dictionary. It can hold any number of keyword arguments.
class obj1:
    def __init__(self, **kwarg):
        self.attributes = kwarg

# t,u,v as actual class attributes
class obj2:
    def __init__(self, t, u, w):
        self.t = t
        self.u = u
        self.w = w

objects1 = []
objects2 = []

with open("input_file", "r") as f:
    lines = []
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        lines.append(line)
        if line.startswith("W"):
            objects1.append(obj1(t=lines[-3], u=lines[-2], w=lines[-1]))
            objects2.append(obj2(t=lines[-3], u=lines[-2], w=lines[-1]))
            lines = []


# same output but different ways of accessing the attributes

for o in objects1:
    print o.attributes["t"]
    print o.attributes["u"]
    print o.attributes["w"]

for o in objects2:
    print o.t
    print o.u
    print o.w
```

input file:

```
$ cat input_file 
total number:18572084
T   2009-06-01 21:43:59
U   http://twitter.com/burtonator 
W   No Post Title

T   2009-06-01 21:47:23
U   http://twitter.com/burtonator
W   No Post Title

T   2009-06-02 01:15:44
U   http://twitter.com/burtonator
W   No Post Title
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the lines in your doc are space separated you would do something like this:

```
class YourObj(object):
    def __init__(self, t, u, w):
        self.t = t
        self.u = u
        self.w = w

all_objs = []

with open("somefile.txt") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for i in range(len(lines)/3):
        all_objs.append(YourObj(t=lines[i], u=lines[i+1], w=lines[i+2])) 

all_objs  # all yours to work on now
```

Comment: You probably mean `t=lines[i*3], u=lines[i*3+1], w=lines[i*3+2]` or, alternatively, `for i in range(0, len(lines), 3): ...`.

Answer (score 0):

I Like Luke's answer, but it looks to me like you'd need something more like this for your specific format:

```
class YourObj(object):
    def __init__(self, dictionary): #init class with dictionary storing data
        self.T = dictionary['T']
        self.U = dictionary['U']
        self.W = dictionary['W']

all_objs = []
with open("somefile.txt") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for i in range(0, len(lines), 3): #read lines in groups of three
        dic = {}
        for j in range(3):
            pieces = lines[i+j].split()
            dic[pieces[0]] = pieces[1] #save data to dictionary
        all_objs.append(YourObj(dic)) #make new object
```